# Grafana: How to auto assign `Admin` user to `Main Org.` and all the others to a separate Org?

Tags: grafana

When I'm running Grafana Server for the first time, I want to assign the `Admin` user to the `Main Org.`
But I also want all the newly created users to be assigned to a different organisation.

I tried setting `auto_assign_org = false` field in Grafana configuration.
It ended up creating new org for each user and a separate `Main Org.` with zero member.

So, how can I assign `Admin` user to the `Main Org` and all the other users to a separate org, say `Others` ?

FYI, all things must be decided when I first run the Grafana Server.